# Organizing Your Controllers into Sub-directories CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I want to create the adminpanel of my site in codeigniter and I want to manage the controllers of adminpanel in separate folder. I have created a folder "admin" in controllers and a controller "Home.php" in controllers/admin.

Now when I try to access this controller using 
http://localhost/web/admin/home/

it gives me 404 error.

I also added $route["admin"] = "admin/home"; in routes.php file.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
MY .htaccess FILE

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Azuaj
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|library|user_guide|robots\.txt)
#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|library|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: have you added htacces in your project?? if not you shud have index.php in your url... http://localhost/web/index.php/admin/home/

Comment: yes I have added the .htaccess file

Comment: try adding index.php in url once...

Comment: Yes I did and it worked. May be I need to change htaccess accordinngly. Can you help on what I should change there?

Comment: add the .htaccess content and try once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

this should help you..

Comment: can you remove the route in routes.php once and try, this is a trial n error one, but just try once..

Comment: still not working. My htaccess file is placed in the root directory, not in application. is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89684/discussion-between-niranjan-and-syed-rizwan-ali).

Answer (score 0):

I know that your problem was already solved through `.htaccess`, but you may find interesting to know that you could have accomplished your goal with an extension.

https://github.com/ollierattue/codeigniter-multi-level-controller-extension